# Redo char is undeclared yet it is declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting a error with redo char (in bold) on main.cpp when I obviously declare it above. I also would like to know why its asking me to put a semicolon in front of using namespace std since I've never done that before.

```
//ReverseString.h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class StringClass
{
public:
string string;
int GetStringLength (char*);
void Reverse(char*);
void OutputString(char*);
void UserInputString (char*);
StringClass();
private:
    int Length;
}

//StringClass.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ReverseString.h"

;using namespace std;

void StringClass::UserInputString(char *string)
{
cout << "Input a string you would like to be reversed.\n";
cin >> string;
cout << "The string you entered: " << string << endl;
}
int StringClass::GetStringLength (char *string)
{
Length = strlen(string);
return Length;
}
void StringClass::Reverse(char *string) 
{
 int c;
 char *front, *rear, temp;

 front = string;
 rear = string;

 GetStringLength(string);

 for ( c = 0 ; c < ( Length - 1 ) ; c++ )
  rear++;

 for ( c = 0 ; c < Length/2 ; c++ ) 
 {        
  temp = *rear;
  *rear = *front;
  *front = temp;

  front++;
  rear--;
 }
} 
void StringClass::OutputString(char *string)
{
cout << "Your string reversed is: " << string << ".";
}

//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "ReverseString.h"

;using namespace std;

const int MaxSize = 100;

int main()
{
do
{
    char string[MaxSize];
    **char redo;**

    StringClass str;

    str.UserInputString(string);

    str.Reverse(string);

    str.OutputString(string);

    //Asks user if they want redo the program
    cout << "Would you like to redo the program?\n";
    cout << "Please enter Y or N: \n";
    **cin >> redo;**
}while(redo == 'Y' || redo == 'y');
}
```

It's really confusing of why its declaring it but giving an error that it isn't declared.

Comment: You're asking for buffer overflows with that input function. And the semicolon doesn't go before the using directive. It goes after what's before that in the code (keeping in mind #includes are copy-pasted).

Comment: How can I restrict buffer overflows in the input? @chris

Comment: Just input a `std::string` instead of a `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redo` is declared as a local variable within the loop. Its scope starts at the point of declaration, and ends at the closing brace right before `while` keyword. The name `redo` is not known within the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon after your class declaration in `ReverseString.h`.

The compiler is picking up the error on the line `using namespace std;` because that is when a problem is first detected.  That doesn't mean that you should put the semi-colon there.

Some compilers will hint that you might be missing a semi-colon from a class declaration, while others will not.  This mistake is quite common.  If you see the *missing semi-colon* error in a ridiculous place, you should immediately consider that you might have accidentally left one out of your headers.

Comment: Thank you! @paddy I would've never guessed that.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that other bit for some reason.  There's already an answer on that.